# How does chatroulette anonymous video and audio work?

Tags: video, video-streaming, chat, videochat

Out of curiosity, what kind of system is in place on Chatroulette sites? I'm guessing its not XMPP, and I don't see how it can be anonymous. Do they just record IPs and start streaming between them? Are there any tools for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the RTMFP protocol - this guy writes about how it works - http://www.bradymoritz.com/how-does-chatroulette-work-the-rtmfp-protocol